# Command to completely uninstall puppet in the agent

Tags: unix, puppet

I have tried `sudo yum remove puppet` and it uninstalled Puppet. But the certificate and repository are all still there.

How do I wipe out everything?

Comment: maybe `rm -rf /etc/puppet /var/lib/puppet`, not all rpm packages clean up after themselves.

Comment: this should be on serverfault, not stackoverflow

Comment: It is normal and intentional that removing an RPM removes only those files that were installed as part of the RPM.  If additional files were written in directories belonging to the RPM then the directories and extra files will be left behind, and the directories might then not be owned by any RPM.  In that case, if you want to remove the extras as well then you need to do so manually.  This has nothing specifically to do with Puppet.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration can vary depending on version of Puppet you're using, and if you're using Puppet Enterprise or not.

But if you want to be super sure you could do this:

```
rm -rf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet
rm -rf /etc/puppet
```

I ran am rpm -e debug and the following config folders are removed by the RPM:

```
D: erase      100644  1 (   0,   0)    39 /etc/tmpfiles.d/puppet.conf
D: erase      100644  1 (   0,   0)   853 /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
D: erase      040755  2 (   0,   0)     6 /etc/puppet/modules
D: erase      100644  1 (   0,   0)  4178 /etc/puppet/auth.conf
D: erase      040755  2 (   0,   0)     6 /etc/puppet
D: erase      100644  1 (   0,   0)   256 /etc/logrotate.d/puppet
```

What files remain when you remove the package?